# Problem trying to export my Tensor Flow model to TLITE

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-lite

After training my model on the GoogleColab following [this tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_image_retraining.ipynb#scrollTo=L1otmJgmbahf) when I try to run  `model.export('image_classifier.tflite', 'image_labels.txt')` it shows me

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-4d5419f8b12d> in <module>()
----> 1 model.export('image_classifier.tflite', 'image_labels.txt')

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_customization/core/task/image_classifier.py in export(self, tflite_filename, label_filename, **kwargs)
    185       else:
    186         quantized = False
--> 187       self._export_tflite(tflite_filename, label_filename, quantized)
    188     else:
    189       raise ValueError('Model Export Format %s is not supported currently.' %

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_customization/core/task/classification_model.py in _export_tflite(self, tflite_filename, label_filename, quantized)
    130       quantized: boolean, if True, save quantized model.
    131     """
--> 132     converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(self.model)
    133     if quantized:
    134       converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE]

AttributeError: type object 'TFLiteConverter' has no attribute 'from_keras_model
```

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow are you using? It is more likely that you are using a 1.x version of TF

Comment: Thanks, I was using version 1 as you said, that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved updating the Tensorflow version, I was using the version 1.X and the TensorFlow changed a lot in the new version IF YOU ARE USING COLAB FROM GOOGLE the version still is 1.X and will change to 2 soon so try to build your model in another way.